# AS3 - TypeError # 1009 with Timers

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

I just have no idea what to do with this. I've been looking through this for an hour now and I keep getting an error reading:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Shooter_Enemy/shotHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

When I debug it it points to the line of the code where "seekingBullet" is added to the stage. Any help resolving this would be greatly welcomed.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Shooter_Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
        private var yMove:int = 2;
        private var shootTimer:Timer = new Timer(500);

        public function Shooter_Enemy()
        {
            this.name = "mc_shooter_enemy";
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enemyMove);

            shootTimer.start();
            shootTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,shotHandler);
        }

        public function addShooterEnemy(X:int):void
        {
            this.x = X;
            this.y = 0;
        }
        public function removeEnemy()
        {
            shootTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,shotHandler);
            shootTimer.stop();

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enemyMove);
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = (stage.height + this.height);
        }
        private function shotHandler(te:TimerEvent):void
        {
            var seekingBullet:SeekingBullet = new SeekingBullet();
            Main.seekingBulletArray.push(seekingBullet);
            stage.addChild(seekingBullet);
            seekingBullet.addSeekingBullet(this.x,this.y);
        }
        private function enemyMove(e:Event)
        {
            this.y +=  yMove;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about Main? Where is it initialized and is seekingBulletArray created?

Comment: what happens when you `trace(stage);` before `stage.addChild`

Comment: Try starting the timer after Shooter_Enemy has actually been added to the stage; that is, in the Shooter_Enemy constructor, add an event listener for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE

Comment: I tried tracing the stage before the child is added and it always outputs **[object Stage]** right up until the shooter enemy is destroyed, at which point it outputs **null** and gives me the TypeError. So it definitely is the "stage" in stage.addChild. As for what to do with this information I have no clue... Any thoughts?

Comment: EDIT: Actually I just fixed it by adding: `if (stage)` around the code so it only runs if the stage is true. Fixed the error, but if anybody has anything to add/make it more efficient then by all means suggest away. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If it's actual, a good practice for using stage is listening *Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE* and then starting your activity like:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Shooter_Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
        private var yMove:int = 2;
        private var shootTimer:Timer = new Timer(500);

        public function Shooter_Enemy()
        {
            this.name = "mc_shooter_enemy";
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enemyMove);

            shootTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, shotHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        public function addShooterEnemy(X:int):void
        {
            this.x = X;
            this.y = 0;
        }
        public function removeEnemy()
        {
            shootTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,shotHandler);
            shootTimer.stop();

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enemyMove);
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = (stage.height + this.height);
        }
        private function addedToStageHandler(e:Event)
        {
            shootTimer.start();
        }
        private function shotHandler(te:TimerEvent):void
        {
            var seekingBullet:SeekingBullet = new SeekingBullet();
            Main.seekingBulletArray.push(seekingBullet);
            stage.addChild(seekingBullet);
            seekingBullet.addSeekingBullet(this.x,this.y);
        }
        private function enemyMove(e:Event)
        {
            this.y +=  yMove;
        }
    }
}
```